# how to get async api calls details using `window.performance.getEntries`

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

Is there any way to get network related information in chrome console.

I have found that **window.performance.getEntries** provide information but it is just for initial page load.

Is there any other way OR need to configure some thing in chrome to get network entries on each user action.